# Delaying evaluation by wrapping parameter in a function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

In Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming [Chapter 8](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch08.html#old-mcdonald-had-effects), they define a new class, `IO`, with the following definition:

```js
class IO {
  static of(x) {
    return new IO(() => x);
  }

  constructor(fn) {
    this.$value = fn;
  }

  map(fn) {
    return new IO(compose(fn, this.$value));
  }

  inspect() {
    return `IO(${inspect(this.$value)})`;
  }
}
```

The author explains:

> `IO` delays the impure action by capturing it in a function wrapper. As
>   such, we think of `IO` as containing the return value of the wrapped
>   action and not the wrapper itself. This is apparent in the of
>   function: we have an `IO(x)`, the `IO(() => x)` is just necessary to avoid
>   evaluation.

But I'm confused on how the `.of()` method delays evaluation at all. For example, going off the definition from the beginning of the section,

```js
// getFromStorage :: String -> (_ -> String)
const getFromStorage = key => () => localStorage[key];
```

If I were to try creating a new `IO` object like `IO.of(localStorage[42])`, for example, this wouldn't delay evaluation at all. The value of `localStorage[42]` would evaluate immediately (say it evaluates to `"foo"`), and then the new `IO` object would be created with `{ $value: () => "foo" }`.

I understand how calling the constructor **directly** like `new IO(key => () => localStorage[key])` delays evaluation, but I don't understand what the author means with the use of the `.of()` method and how that "avoids evaluation". Additionally, the author doesn't use `.of()` in any of the examples for `IO`, instead calling the constructor directly.

Comment: For monads `of` means to put a pure value into the context of the respective monad, `IO` (better `Defer`) in this case. That means there isn't anything to defer anymore. The value is already evaluated when you put it into the context. Doing so ist still sensible since you can work with this pure value within the `IO` monad now.

Comment: @bob Ah that makes sense. Then what does the author mean by saying "This is apparent in the `of` function: we have an `IO(x)`, the `IO(() => x)` is just necessary to avoid evaluation." We're no longer avoiding evaluation with this pure value, since, as you said, it's already evaluated.

Comment: I think Brian just tries to make another point, namely that we shouldn't think of `IO` as a nullary function. It's a bit hard to follow his thought at this particular point.

Comment: This is actually a good example why we need `of` as part of the monad API and not just the respective constructor. They can differ like with `IO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `IO` to be monadic (according to that book's conception of monads), it needs an `.of` method that can wrap any arbitrary value in an `IO`. `IO.of` does that. Since the nature of this book's implementation of `IO`s is that they carry a function that can be evaluated at some later time, the `.of` method wraps the passed value in a function.

`IO.of(5)` creates an instance of `IO` that wraps the value `5`. That is all. There is nothing about `.of` that actually delays an effect.

Regarding your question in the comments:

> Then what does the author mean by saying "This is apparent in the `of` function: we have an IO(x), the IO(() => x) is just necessary to avoid evaluation."

I think the information necessary for understanding that comment is what's right before it:

> We don't think of its $value as a function, however - that is an implementation detail and we best ignore it. ... As such, we think of IO as containing the return value of the wrapped action and not the wrapper itself.

It seems his point is that conceptually, an `IO`'s "value" is the value that the contained function eventually evaluates to, but in order to achieve delayed evaluation, internally, it stores an unevaluated function until such time as it is necessary for the `IO` to resolve to a value.

So you can create an `IO` for the value `5` by calling `IO.of(5)`, but internally, it contains a function that evaluates to `5`, so that at some later time this function can be evaluated to a value.

If you want to create an `IO` that actually delays evaluation for some impure effect, use the constructor and pass it a function.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you! So to clarify, the key difference is that with `.of`, there really is no delay in evaluation in the sense that whatever gets passed to `of` is evaluated immediately and stored. However, a key part of the API for `IO` is that its value internally is a function that can be evaluated. So to achieve this we just wrap anything in a function to allow us to do `ioObject.$value()` for any object of type `IO`?

Comment: @rb612 Yes, that's right. As I understand it, the `.of` method on the various monad types is rarely intended to be used directly, but exists so that you can create abstractions that work with any monad type (e.g. a `flatMap` function that works equally well with an `IO`, `Maybe`, `List` or any other type of monad). The presence of an `.of` method makes that possible and is fundamental to the concept of monads.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes, `of` has a more general type (`a => m a` where m has a monad constraint) than a specific data constructor like `List` or `Maybe` so it can be used to write generic monadic code that works for any monad. `map` lifts a pure function into the context of a functor and applies it inside. `of` just lifts a pure value into the context of an applicative. I wrote applicative not monad, because `of` is part of the applicative functor interface monads inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of `IO.of(x)` as the starting point for impure actions.

For example you may be wanting to read the content of a DOM element and `x` would be its id: (in "pseudo code")

```js
const readInput = id =>
  IO
    .of(id)
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id))
    .map(el => el.textContent)

readInput('#login');
// combine with other monads for example
```